# about list comprehension in python

Tags: python

Im completely stuck with these codes and dont have any idea why this two codes' output is different.

ans

```
str = 'I am an NLPer'
def ngram(n, lst):
    return list(zip(*[lst[i:] for i in range(n)]))
ngram(2,str)
```

output

```
[('I', ' '),
 (' ', 'a'),
 ('a', 'm'),
 ('m', ' '),
 (' ', 'a'),
 ('a', 'n'),
 ('n', ' '),
 (' ', 'N'),
 ('N', 'L'),
 ('L', 'P'),
 ('P', 'e'),
 ('e', 'r')]
```

my code

```
def myngram(n):
    for i in range(n):
        return  list(zip(*str[i:]))
myngram(2)
```

output

```
[('I', ' ', 'a', 'm', ' ', 'a', 'n', ' ', 'N', 'L', 'P', 'e', 'r')]
```

any idea?

I got another solutin down below but that one above is way more sofisticatedd.

```
str = 'I am an NLPer'
list = []
def ngram(n):
    for i in range(len(str)-1):
        list.append((str[i], str[i+1]))
    return(list)

ngram(2)
```

Comment: In your code you have a `for` loop that use you `return` inside. This means the loop never loops more than once. `return` immediately ends the function (and therefor the loop).

Comment: Much simpler way for bigrams: `list(zip(str, str[1:]))`. Your initial list comprehension is a generalization of that for any ngrams.

Comment: and please dont name your string `str`. This is a shadow name. name it `input_str` for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can breakdown the function to have a better understanding of it,

```
[lst[i:] for i in range(n)]
```

will give u an output of 2 list with result,

```
[('I am an NLPer',), (' am an NLPer',)]
```

with the guide on `zip` mention [here](https://realpython.com/python-zip-function/#:%7E:text=Python%27s%20zip()%20function%20is,%2C%20sets%2C%20and%20so%20on.) it would unzip the sequence to the output you mention above.

Comment: thanks guys! I finally figure out what is going on these codes!
```
str = 'I am an NLPer'
li = []
def ngram(n):
    for i in range(n):
         li.append(str[i:])
    return list(zip(*li))
ngram(2)
```